# login to facebook chat using asmack on android with the new access token

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook, xmpp, asmack

I have a FB chat client developed for Android. I've been using [facebook android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) to obtain the access token from a user. Using asmack, user was logged into the chat.
Token was in the form: 226409362971500|3b29bc82baa7901a9baca042.4-72793766|9eb417f06fc376897222938295a0dd0c
The code I used was:

```
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", SASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", 0);
xmpp.connect();
xmpp.login("226409362971500", "3b29bc82baa7901a9fbaca042.4-72793766|9eb417f06fc376897222938295a0dd0c", "Application");
```

Now it seems that Facebook has changed the [token format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357801/strange-access-token-returned-from-facebook).
I have tried logging in with the old token, but I always get XMPPException. I've tried loggin in with the new access token: xmpp.login(token, "Application"), but still no luck.
Any idea how to solve this?